# Sem retorno de geolocalização utilizando Phonegap

Tags: javascript, html, android, apache-cordova

Estou usando o código para pegar a geolocalização do *Phonegap*, mas mesmo assim, quando eu emulo o app, ele não me retorna nada. Existe alguma coisa errada no código?

#### index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>Hello World</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    var watchID = null;
    function onDeviceReady() {
        var options = { enableHighAccuracy: true };
        watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);
    }

    function onSuccess(position) {
        var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
        element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '  + position.coords.latitude      + '<br />' +
                            'Longitude: ' + position.coords.longitude     + '<br />' +
                            '<hr />'      + element.innerHTML;
    }

    // clear the watch that was started earlier
    //
    function clearWatch() {
        if (watchID != null) {
            navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchID);
            watchID = null;
        }
    }

        function onError(error) {
          alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
                'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
        }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="geolocation">Watching geolocation...</p>
        <button onclick="clearWatch();">Clear Watch</button>
  </body>
 </html>
```

#### config.xml

```
<feature name="Geolocation">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.geolocation.GeoBroker" />
</feature>
<feature name="NetworkStatus">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.networkinformation.NetworkManager" />
</feature>
```

#### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: Usando o emulador, é preciso também simular a localização pelo DDMS, caso você esteja usando o Eclipse. Isso já foi feito?

Comment: Eu configurei o AVD seguindo os passos descritos neste link [Developer Android](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds.html#hardwareopts). Configurei o **hw.gps**

Comment: Certo, você configurou o emulador para simular a existência de um GPS, mas isso por si só não te informa as coordenadas. Para isso, abra a perspectiva DDMS e com o emulador iniciado, seleciona a aba Emulator Control e na seção Location Controls você pode manualmente informar uma latitude e longitude para enviar, ai sim o seu GPS simulado irá entrar em ação.

Comment: Muito obrigada. vou configurar aqui e tentar simular o GPS. Caso não consiga, te informo =D

Comment: Olá @LuannaIozzi se você conseguiu achar uma solução por favor poste ela no campo de resposta para outras pessoas com o mesmo problema que você ser beneficiadas ;) Obrigado..

Comment: Então, eu configurei o DDMS na minha maquina e não funcionou, mas uma outra pessoa que esta trabalhando comigo neste projeto, configurou e funcionou normalmente. Acredito que seja as minhas configurações de eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Adicione isso ao seu AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
```

E então tente simular suas localizações dentro do próprio aplicativo e depois no DDMS para verificar se pode ser uma restrição ou bug do PhoneGAP.